# How do I print a statement if a value of a variable changes in python?

Tags: python

Say my code is something like:

```
while True:
    nheight = tc.getblockcount()['count']
```

with tc.getblockcount... being a rpc call, the result is an integer stored in the variable `nheight`. This value changes 30 seconds or so, so how do I make it print a statement when it changes? Right now I've done something like this:

```
height = tc.getblockcount()['count']

while True:

    nheight = tc.getblockcount()['count']

    if height != nheight:

            print("Val Changed")

            height = nheight

            time.sleep(0.4)
```

So the hope is that when `nheight` changes, it detects it because it differs from `height`, which had the original same value. Then it updates the value `height` so that it doesnt keep printing `Val Changed` because the value changed once. Then it sleep for 0.4 seconds and loops again

The problem right now is that it prints "Val Changed" once but doesnt again, even when the value changes (which i've verified by inserting a few print statements)

Could someone help me with making something which will print something when the value of nheight changes?

Also if possible, since the rest of my code isn't made using OOP, and I don't understand it well, the examples are given without OOP?

(there's something called the observer pattern which i think does this, is that correct?)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You should try printing the value of bothering heights before the if statement and show us the output

Comment: Do you see it change if you run `while True: print(tc.getblockcount()['count'])`, because your code looks fine

Comment: Yea its actually like:
 
    while True:
     nheight = tc.getblockcount()['count']
 print(nheight)
 print(height)
    if height != nheight:
        print("val changed")    
        height = nheight
        time.sleep (0.4) 

@cricket_007

Comment: Yes it updates @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: I got it to work with some help, problem was with another part of the code
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

since i dont know what tc.getblockcount is here is a function that returns mostly the same number but 10% of the time it changes

```
def value_iter():
    last_value = 1
    while True:
        yield last_value
        if random.random() < 0.1:
           last_value = last_value + 1

def getblockcount(it=value_iter()):
    return next(it)

height = getblockcount()
while True:
    nheight = getblockcount()
    print(nheight,"=?=",height)
    if nheight != height:
       print("UPDATE!\n\n")
       height=nheight
```

as you can see if you copy this it works as expected

Comment: Could you explain why this code works and the code in the question doesn't? As far as I can tell, it's basically the same code.

Comment: Not sure if I understand; my script is asking a program for what the current "height" is, which changes every about 30 seconds. Your script seems to rely on the value iterator thing, is there anyway I could do something like this (it works like expected on console) without the first def?